# Including a Pre-Built .so Library in my Android Project

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android.mk

Well, I am trying to use a pre-built .so library for my Android Project.

I've been reading several threads at stackoverflow and from the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html#dm), but still have several doubts.
For what I understood, I only need to put the library into a specific folder, then create an mk file and once press refresh. Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

[image]

My Android.mk file has the following content:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyApplication
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/androhid.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And I put the files in the followings paths:

[image: Structure]

How can fix the previously commented error?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need ndk-build to add a prebuilt lib to your APK. You can pin jniLibs to app/libs in build.gradle